# EmberJS | How is outlet loaded inside application.hbs

Tags: ember.js

I am new to EmberJS,
Can someone please explain how EmberJS loads the outlet inside application.hbs?

I know application.hbs is the starting point, from where the router.js will invoked that will call the default resource.
I am lost on how the default resource loads another template into the applcation.hbs.

Comment: By visiting a different url which corresponds to your router.

Comment: @Kingpin2k I am asking about the default route. Not a different url achieved by visiting it.
The default route loads a base application hbs and then the required template. How is the link set between the two?

Comment: It isn't, the root of the app `/` specifically doesn't show anything other than the `application` template (and the index template if you are just in the root), the outlet is designed for when you are visiting sub routes under the application template

Comment: http://cball.me/understanding-loading-substates-in-ember/

Comment: An outlet is not "loaded", it is "rendered into". Subroutes render their templates into the outlet(s) of the parent routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem quite confused. I suggest going through the Ember guide again.

> I know `application.hbs` is the starting point

No, it's the template rendered by the top-level route.

> from where `router.js` will invoked that will call the default resource

Templates do not invoke routes, they are rendered by routes.

> I am lost on how the default resource loads another template into the applcation.hbs.

When you visit a route, that route's template is rendered into an outlet in the template corresponding to a higher-level route.

Answer (score 0):

Read this from the url:
http://thetechcofounder.com/getting-started-with-ember-js-using-ember-cli/

A router resource [essentially current url path ] is linked to a template. So the moment that resource is encountered, ember brings in the template that is specified with the router resource and replaces the outlet in the application template.